Running a Spark Master and an SSH server in the same Docker container
I need to run a spark master and an ssh server on the same docker container, I know it is not recommended to run multiple services in one container, but i need the SSH service to make my spark cluster able to receive remotely submitted spark jobs (from Apache Airflow).
This is my compose.yml file for the Spark cluster:
services:
  spark-master:
    build: ./spark-master-ssh-server/.
    command: bash -c "/usr/sbin/sshd -D && bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"

    ports:
      - "9095:8080" # Spark Web UI
      - "7777:7077" #spark master port
      - "22222:22"  #ssh port
      #- "8998:8998"
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-1:
    build: .
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      #SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      #SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-2:
    build: .
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      #SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      #SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network


networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge

And the following is the Dockerfile for building the Spark muster image:
FROM bitnami/spark:latest

# Install SSH server
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y openssh-server

# Create an SSH user
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/sshuser -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 sshuser

# Set the SSH user's password
RUN echo 'sshuser:password' | chpasswd

## Generate SSH host keys
RUN ssh-keygen -A 

# Expose the SSH port
EXPOSE 22


# Switch to sshuser
USER sshuser

But the container is not running in the first place and I know it is because of the command: bash -c "/usr/sbin/sshd -D && bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master", but I have also tried starting the ssh server with:
# Start SSH server on container startup (in Dockerfle: ./spark-master-ssh-server/.)

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

and starting the Spark master like this:
  spark-master:
    build: ./spark-master-ssh-server/.
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9095:8080" # Spark Web UI
      - "7777:7077" #spark master port
      - "22222:22"  #ssh port
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network

But with the above code the command starting SSH in Dockerfile ./spark-master-ssh-server/. is being overridden by command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master in compose.yml and SSH is not running.

And if there is a better way of making Airflow submit spark jobs to a remote Spark cluster I am open to any suggestions.
